# Azure Stack REST APIs

Tags: azure

We are looking for Azure stack Resource REST APIs. we want to handle Azure stack Resources like Resource groups, Virtual machines, Vnet, Subnet, etc. using REST APIs, can anyone point us to any link or document so where we can get all these APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The API for Azure Stack, is the same API you would use for talking to normal Azure, for the services Azure Stack provides, that's the point of Azure Stack, to provide a consistent interface for stack and main Azure.
The main difference is that you need to us a different management URL when talking to your Azure Stack instance. You can see how to set this up [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-rest-api-use?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404)